# iOS scrollview not working

Tags: ios, scrollview, scroller

Someone please help ive been trying to sort this out for the past 5 hours and im starting to go mad!

In my scrollview ive got a image at the top and a text box at the bottom just so I know that its working when i go into the iOS 6.1 iphone simulator it doesn't fully scroll, it will go down a little bit but not all the way. Im not using storyboards before anyone asks again and im a complete self taught idiot when it comes to coding, ive been looking at youtube videos on how to do it and ive followed it down to a tea and yet its still not working.

**viewcontroller.h**
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

}   


@end
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,910)];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Is that all your source code?? Where did you initialize the `scroller` and add it to the `ViewController`'s view?

Comment: Interface builder, I guess.

Comment: If you problem was resolved means please accept any of the following answer. It will be helpful for beginners to get solution from your post.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this works.
Set your view controller - uncheck Autolayout

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 1700)];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 6.1 you should put code for scrollview not in viewDidLoad method, but in viewDidAppear method:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 910)];
}
```

It should work!

Answer (score 1):

```
 (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 1700)];
}
```

After writing this code your scrollview not working just doing these easy steps after writing this code.

1. select your scroll view.`enter code here`
2. go to the write most top option in xcode open utilities bar .
3. after doing this you see the autoresizing option click on this and select and side .
4. Run your code your code is working now.

**Enjoy and thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,910)];
    [self.view addSubView:scroller];
}
```

You need to initialize the scroller to have a viewable area (change width and height to your preference) and with a longer contentSize, then it will scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{     
     UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 350, 150)];
     scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
     scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
     scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
     scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(350,150);
     scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
     [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```